# while I am calling my py file from jenkins groovy script, I am getting an error in "from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient"

Tags: python, azure, jenkins, jenkins-groovy, azure-data-lake

While i am calling my py file from a jenkins pipeline script which is written in groovy.
It has a line "from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient"
and my py file has a dependancy on this "DataLakeServiceClient" method.
so when i run the pipeline in jenkins, this is the error coming up

***from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/filedatalake/**init**.py", line 7, in 
from ._download import StorageStreamDownloader
File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/filedatalake/_download.py", line 8, in 
from ._deserialize import from_blob_properties
File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/filedatalake/_deserialize.py", line 15, in 
from ._models import FileProperties, DirectoryProperties, LeaseProperties, DeletedPathProperties, StaticWebsite, 

File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/filedatalake/_models.py", line 11, in 
from azure.storage.blob import LeaseProperties as BlobLeaseProperties
ImportError: cannot import name 'LeaseProperties' from 'azure.storage.blob' (/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/**init**.*py)**

and my pipline is getting stopped.
I tried to explicitly mention "python3 -m pip install azure-storage-blob", but of no use
i am still getting the same error.

can somebody help me out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are installing the wrong package. You need to install the `azure-storage-file-datalake` package using pip to use the `DataLakeServiceClient` class. Use the below command to install this package:

`pip install azure-storage-file-datalake --pre`

I suggest you to please go through the [official pip documentation](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-file-datalake/) to know more about this library.

Comment: Hi Utkarsh , thanks for replying
I am installing  
  python3 -m pip install azure-storage-file-datalake --pre
            python3 -m pip install azure
            python3 -m pip install azure-identity
            python3 -m pip install azure-keyvault-secrets
            python3 -m pip install azure-storage-blob

all these packages, before calling my python file from groovy script.
the error is still there

Comment: I'm assuming you must be using pip3. just uninstall the existing azure-storage-file-datalake package and install again using "pip install azure-storage-file-datalake --pre" command.